How can I send Gcode commands to Arduino (GRBL) serial monitor using python script
import serial
import time

# Define the serial port and baud rate
serial_port = "COM5"  # Change this to your serial port
baud_rate = 115200  # Change this to match the baud rate of your device

# Define the list of G-code commands
coms = [
    "G90",
    "G21",
    "G92 X0 Y0",
    "G1 F1000",
    "M5 S90",
    "G4 P0.2",
    "G1 F1000",
    "G1 X20",
    "G1 Y20",
    "G1 X0",
    "G1 Y0",
    "M3",
]

# Open the serial port
ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate, timeout=1)

try:
    if ser.is_open:
        print(f"Serial port {serial_port} opened successfully.")
        
        while True:
            # Read data from the serial port
            data = ser.readline().decode().strip()
            if data:
                print("Received:", data)

            user_input = input("Enter command (X for unlock, H for homing, G-code command): ").strip().upper()

            if user_input == "X":
                print("Unlocking the system")
                ser.write(b"$X")
            elif user_input == "H":
                print("Activating homing cycle")
                ser.write(b"$H")
            else:
                print("Sending G-code commands...")
                for command in coms:
                    print("Sending:", command)
                    ser.write(command.encode())
                    time.sleep(1)  # Add a delay between commands if needed

            # Wait for response from CNC machine
            grbl_out = ser.readline().decode().strip()
            print("Response:", grbl_out)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Keyboard interrupt detected. Exiting...")

finally:
    # Close the serial port
    if ser.is_open:
        ser.close()
        print("Serial port closed.")

Here's a brief summary of the provided Python script:
This script allows users to communicate with an Arduino (GRBL) CNC controller via the serial port. It provides a command-line interface for sending G-code commands to the CNC machine.
Key Features:

Opens a serial connection to the specified COM port.
Reads data from the serial port and displays it.
Accepts user input to send commands to the CNC machine:

"X" to unlock the system.
"H" to activate the homing cycle.
Any other input sends a series of predefined G-code commands to the CNC machine.


Sends G-code commands sequentially with a delay between each command.
Displays responses from the CNC machine.

The script is designed to be interactive and provides feedback to the user throughout the process of sending commands and receiving responses from the CNC machine.
Components using:
1.Arduino Uno
2.CNC shield V3 (protneer)
3.Stepper motor (Nema 17)
4.servo motor (SG90)
5.A4988 driver
6.GRBL framework

Your question is "How can I send Gcode commands to Arduino (GRBL) serial monitor using python script", yet you show us a functioning code to communcating with an arduino using pyserial. What is your real question? What to write on the arduino side?
